# Microsoft PowerPoint 2010 Presentation Help Needed

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-office-2010

I want to create a PowerPoint Presentation for a star studded event that I am having. I want the slides to have a STAR with my headshot photo to come out of it. For example, I will be giving out awards to people and they will be in the audience. When I click on the slide, they will see a STAR, and out of the star, I want my headshot picture or their headshot picture to pop up. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

This is fairly straightforward.

1. First add the star to the slide.
2. Insert the picture and resize to the end result you desire.
3. Choose the **Animation** tab.
4. With the picture selected, choose **Zoom** from the list.

You can preview and adjust the effect options from the **Animation Pane**

[image]

The results:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me. I have added the star and the picture with the animation. I see that the animation is there, but the animation doesn't play until I click on it. I tried setting the delay to 00.25 and that doesn't seem like it's working. To test it, I go back to the previous slide and then click on the animated slide with the star...at this point, I should only see a Star without the photo picture, but I see both. Did I miss something?

Comment: Are you testing it in slideshow? Also, you can adjust the trigger to be other than a click in the timing options.

Comment: The animations and slides will run accordingly if you are in SlideShow mode (press F5). You can set the animations to be activated in different ways: run on click, run after/with the previous. In Normal Mode (editing mode) it's only a preview mode for the animations.

Comment: @CharlieRB I wasn't testing it in a slideshow, but that you mentioned it, I tried it and it works on the clicks. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help. If you feel this answers your question, please mark it as accepted so other readers will see there is an answer available.